# Writing dynamic data to files in win32

Tags: c++, winapi, dynamic

I'm having trouble with win32. I have to write some dynamic data to a file in win32 using c++. I know the basics of how to write strings to the file, but how can we write a data of ints, floats etc to a file.

I have a file which I'm copying the data to another newly created file. I need to write the data of ints, floats etc to this file at top.
I know we can add the data by

```
char buff[] = "hello";
```

and copy this to file, I don't know how I can do this with different kinds of data types. Any help?

```
char buf[] = "hello";  //Null terminate
LPVOID lpMsgBuf; 
DWORD byteWritten = 0;
HANDLE hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
BOOL ReadFileReturn;

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("MYFILE.blo",    // open MYFILE.blo 
            GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,              
            FILE_SHARE_READ,               // share for reading 
            NULL,                          // no security 
            OPEN_EXISTING,                   // existing file only 
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,         // normal file 
            NULL);                         // no attr
ReadFileReturn = ReadFile(hFile,buf,30,&byteWritten,NULL);    
if(ReadFileReturn)
{
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
                  NULL,
                  GetLastError(),
                  MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
                 (LPTSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
                  0,
                  NULL);
    WriteFile(hStdOut,buf,sizeof buf,NULL,NULL);

}
else
{
    WriteFile(hStdOut,"It Failed",sizeof "It Failed",NULL,NULL);

}
```

Comment: There seems to be some confusion below about how you want to store your data. Can you post an example of what mechanism you are writing a string to a file?

Answer (score 1):

That depends how you are opening your file (in which mode actually). If you have opened them in a text mode, everything regardless of its type will get written in the form of string/text. Otherwise you can choose to open file in binary mode. In that mode `int` will be written as `int`, `float` will be written as `float` etc.

Here's a link for describing the difference between both types of files http://www.fileinfo.com/help/binary_vs_text_files

You can perhaps try something like:

```
char str[80] = "";
int a = 1, b = 2;
int n = sprintf(str, "%d", a+b);
DWORD bytesWritten;
WriteFile(fileHandle, str, strlen(str), &bytesWritten, NULL);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I need this win32. I'm copying binary data to another file and have to add the values. How can I do this in win32?

Comment: Do I have to use WriteFile for each data type?

Comment: I would have thought that using the C++ file interface is a MUCH better choice. Simpler and more consistent.

Comment: @BadSniper I have updated the answer by including a Win32 example. Hope it helps.

Comment: I need to intialize str with argv[], how can I do that? str is char and argv is char*

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/

So basically you do this:

```
 .... 
 std::ofstream myfile("filename");
 double my_data = 15;
 myfile.write( static_cast< const char*>(&my_data), sizeof( double ) );
 ...
```

The previous snippet is a bit crude, you might need to check issues like endiannes and alignment.